# Почему существуют правила «ча-ща» и «чу-щу», но не существует правил «че-ще» и «чо-що»?

Tags: орфография, фонетика

В русском языке есть четыре йотированные гласные буквы: ***я [йа]***, ***ю [йу]***, ***е [йэ]*** и ***ё [йо]***.

Так же есть три согласные буквы, которые всегда обозначают мягкие звуки: ***ч***, ***щ*** и ***й***.

Йотированные гласные буквы в положении после согласной буквы обозначают её мягкость.

Например: в слове ***«мяч»*** согласная буква ***м*** мягкая: ***[м’ач]***, а в слове ***«матч»*** — нет: ***[матч]***.

Из этого следует, что нет никакого смысла писать йотированные буквы ***я [йа]***, ***ю [йу]***, ***е [йэ]*** и ***ё [йо]***, обозначающие мягкость предшествующей согласной буквы, после всегда мягких согласных букв ***ч***, ***щ*** и ***й***.

Нет смысла писать: ***чя-щя*** и ***чю-щю***, потому что бессмысленно обозначать мягкость и так всегда мягких букв: ***ч*** и ***щ*** всегда будут читаться мягко.

Но в отношении букв ***е [йэ]*** и ***ё [йо]*** такого правила нет, хотя было бы логично всегда писать ***чэ-щэ*** и ***чо-що***.

Зачем писать, например, слово «через» с буквой ***е [йэ]*** после ***ч***, если ***ч*** и так всегда обозначает мягкий звук?

***«Через»*** звучит ***[чэр’ес]*** и правильно было бы писать именно с буковой ***э*** после мягкой буквы ***ч***. Никаким ***[й]*** там и не пахнет. А если писать ***«через»*** с буквой ***е [йэ]*** после ***ч***, то это должно читаться как-то ***[ч’йэр’ес]***, но никак не ***[чэр’ес]***.

---

Почему существуют правила ***ча-ща*** и ***чу-щу***, но не существует правил ***че-ще*** и ***чо-що***?

Comment: *«Через» звучит [чэр’ес]* — да нет, [чэ] звучит в украинском варианте слова. Просто произнесите по звукам, чтобы это понять. Щ — всегда мягкая, а вот Ч может произносится как с Я/Ю/Е/Ё/И (часто в русском), так и с А/У/Э/О/Ы (часто в украинском).

Comment: Мягкий звук зависит сам от себя, но не от букв, которые его обозначают. Мягкие звуки — двухфокусные. У них дополнительно поднимается к нёбу спинка языка — это и есть второй фокус. Так, к примеру, получается мягкий Т и твердый Т. А вот звук Ч может в русском языке звучать только мягко, такова его природа. Вероятно, мы привыкли к такой артикуляции.

Comment: @Sharon *А вот звук Ч может в русском языке звучать только мягко* — пусть так, но Ч можно произнести и твёрдо (в отличие от Щ), что происходит в украинском языке.

Comment: @oleedd «_„Через“ звучит [чэр’ес]_ — да нет, [чэ] звучит в украинском варианте слова» — у меня правильная транскрипция. В русском языке _**ч**_ мягкое, а в украинском — твёрдое поэтому так кажется.

Comment: @Sharon _«Мягкий звук зависит сам от себя, но не от букв, которые его обозначают»._ «Гласные Е, Ё, Ю, Я дают один звук … если стоят после согласных … и **обозначают мягкость предшествующего согласного звука**» [[izamorfix.ru](https://izamorfix.ru/rus/fonetika/glasnye_zvuki.html)]. И это не только в этом источнике. Речь не о том, как появляются мягкие звуки в устной речи, а о том, как они обозначаются на письме. Для того чтоб указать, что согласный звук мягкий, после него пишут йотированную гласную, а не обычную. (1/2)

Comment: @Sharon Конечно, в устной речи звуки не могут зависеть от букв, потому что буквы это запись звуков, а не наоборот. (2/2)

Comment: @oleedd _«пусть так, но Ч можно произнести и твёрдо (в отличие от Щ), что происходит в украинском языке»_ — мы говорим про русский язык; правила произношения украинского языка не имеют отношения к моему вопросу. Можно рассмотреть ещё другие славянские языки и найти много отличий в произношении. В русском языке _**ч**_ твёрдо не произносится в настоящее время, поэтому нет смысла обозначать его мягкость йотированной гласной.

Comment: Произносится оно так: *[ч’ер’ес]*. Два Е произносятся одинаково — мягко и без Й. Что-то не так с логикой, почему не *[ч’йер’**й**ес]*? Мысль в том, что если звук может быть и твёрдым и мягким, то с научной точки зрения важно показать, какой он именно, вне зависимости от употребления.

Answer (score 1):

На правах комментария

1. Я вряд ли готова участвовать в дискуссии на тему шипящих, хотя уделяла достаточно много времени ее изучению. Почему? Тема составлена из многих **частных разделов,** и каждый из них требует отдельного обсуждения и понимания.

(1) Здесь и особенности **непарных по мягкости-твердости** шипящих звуков, которые требовалось  вписать в общую систему графических правил (а это особые правила).

(2) Здесь и особенности **самой графики**,  а именно тесная историческая связь букв О/Е/Ё и букв Э/Е. («Молодые» буквы Э и Ё не могут выполнять свою работу в полной мере, и тогда их заменяет буква Е.)

(3) Буквы Е, Ё, Ю, Я **выполняют двойную работу**: в начале слова и после гласного обозначают йотированный гласный, а  после согласного  обозначают его мягкость.
Примечание. Почему такие разные обязанности? В действительности они довольно похожи, сравним: лю – лью;  л(и)у – л(й)у.  Краткий призвук «и», характерный для мягкого согласного, легко переходит в звук «й»

(4) **Также важно учитывать:** историческую графику и фонетику, изменение звуков, происхождение букв, сложившиеся традиции письма. Например, когда-то все шипящие были мягкими, и поэтому нам в наследство досталась редукция гласных  после них по мягкому варианту. Эту «живую историю» мы видим и в современной речи:  Ни ж(Ы)лею, ни зову, ни плачу…

Так что одной современной фонетикой выбор гласных после шипящих объяснить невозможно.

2. Та система правил, которая была принята в 1956 году,  поражает той **ювелирной точностью,**  с которой были решены все названные проблемы.  Нет  возможности предложить ничего лучшего,  хотя  тему много раз пытались реформировать.
3. **Постановка задачи** была предельно проста: нужно было выбрать одну из парных гласных букв  А – Я, О – Ё, У – Ю, Э – Е, Ы – И после шипящих. Полученное решение мы можем кратко прокомментировать и обосновать – это все, что пользователям желательно понимать в этой теме. Если какой-то выбор не устраивает, то его можно обсудить.
4. **Освоение правописания шипящих**  на практике несложно, но для этого нужна хорошая **методика** – у нас же ее нет. Школьники учат правила, но вряд до конца понимают их смысл. Тем не менее за 11 лет материал (ввиду ограниченности объема) постепенно усваивается.
5. Соответственно,  имеет смысл обсуждать только  **очень частные детали**, при этом желательно, чтобы собеседники имели  одинаковое общее понимание всей темы.
6. **Коротко можно сказать следующее.**

Написания **ЧА-ЩА и ЧУ-ЩУ** –  это **очень давняя традиция**, в другом виде эти сочетания  практически не встречались. Это связано с историей самих букв Я и Ю, которые утвердились на письме не сразу.  https://www.sites.google.com/site/skazobukvah/istoria

**Буква Ё** после шипящих пишется преимущественно в корнях с чередованием (чернеть – чёрный) и в глагольных формах (печёт, печёный, выкорчёвывать). Это тоже способ вписаться в общую систему письма (темнеть – тёмный, несёт, унесенный), чтобы части речи узнавались по форме (**интегрирующий** принцип, который почему-то называют дифференцирующим).

**Буква Э** после согласных вообще пишется не часто (ее обычно заменяет Е), поэтому после шипящих не пишется тем более.

Мы видим, что при решении в большей степени учитывалась не современная фонетика, а  **исторические традиции и грамматические показатели**.

Answer (score 1):

Сразу оговорюсь, что на вопрос в том виде, как он задан, нельзя ответить корректно. "Почему" предполагает какую-то причинно-следственную связь, а её в филологии, как правило, нет. Так сложилось. В данном случае все определяется сложившимися подходами.  Поэтому я буду говорить не о причинах, а просто о принципах русской орфографии в свете данных "правил".

Правила же, о которых вы говорите, на самом деле - не правила, а орфограмки-запоминалки, построенные на других, более глубоких правилах. Забегая чуть вперед скажу, что правила эти строятся совсем не на том, как можно произнести сочетание, а на принципах орфографии в целом. Целевая аудитория подобных орфограмок - школьники. Запоминалки эти совсем не ставят себе целью покрыть все поле возможных сочетаний, они сосредоточены на случаях, где реально возможны ошибки. И вы это прекрасно понимаете, вам даже не пришло в голову включить в список рекомендуемых вами "по смыслу" сочетаний "ЧЫ" и "ЩЫ", хотя "И" точно такая же смягчающая гласная и (с некоторыми оговорками) является "мягким" вариантом фонемы Ы. А вот студентам РКИ иногда дают и те правила, которые вы считаете "несуществущими". Это и ответ на ваше второе посему.
"Почему существуют правила ча-ща и чу-щу, но не существует правил че-ще и чо-що?".
Не совсем, правда, понятно, как в этот вопрос попали *чо* и *що* - правил на них не существует, как ***не существует и самих таких сочетаний*** - за исключением заимствованных имен собственных:*Чоп (город), Чорный, Чорлука (фамилия) и проч*.

Теперь о главном.

> Из этого следует, что нет никакого смысла писать йотированные буквы йотированные
> буквы я [йа], ю [йу], е [йэ] и ё [йо], обозначающие мягкость предшествующей
> согласной буквы, после всегда мягких согласных букв ч, щ и й.

Не следует. Вы очень однобоко понимаете "смысл" орфографических правил.
В русской орфографии выделяются три (в некоторых источниках - четыре или пять) базовых принципа: ***морфологический***, ***фонетический или фонемный*** (из которого иногда выделяют как отдельный принцип  **фонематический**), ***традиционный*** и, по некоторым источникам, ***дифференцирующий***.

Вот достаточно полное описание каждого из таких принципов.
https://myfilology.ru/russkiiyazyk/orfografiia/printsipy-russkoi-orfografii-analiz-glavneishikh-pravil-russkoi-orfografii-s-tochki-zreniia-ee-osnovnogo-printsipa/
(источник не авторитетный но очень содержательный).

Всего принципов больше (например, принципы регулирующие слитное и раздельное написание, "не" и "ни" и другие), но остальные играют второстепенную роль и их обычно не рассматривают в списки базовых.

Основным и главным принципом русской орфографии является **морфологический принцип**. Этот принцип не заключается в том, что написание любой морфологически значимой части слова, появляющейся в разных словах, всегда одинаково, не зависит от произношения. На нем построено до 90% всех правил русской орфографии.

На нём, построено, в частности, и правило написания сочетания **ЧЁ** и **ЩЁ** в корнях слов. Под ударением там фонетическое О, но без ударения - Е.

**ЧЕ** и **ЩЕ** тоже завязаны на морфологию слов. Буква Э - сравнительно новая в алфавмте и имеет ограниченное употребление. Кодификация написаний ЧЭ и ЩЭ потребовала бы пересмотра всей системы сложившейся морфологии

Что касается сочетаний **ЧУ** и **ЩУ**, то морфологический принцип там тоже присутствует, но исходные морфемы сейчас вышли из живого языка, забылись, поэтому наряду с морфологическим принципом тут включается традиционный.

Вот это общая картина. А "почему" уж так сложилось - ну это вопрос совершенно неподъемный. Могу только добавить, что подобный подход - не есть какой-то абсолют. В близкородственных языках - белорусском и украинском - возможны написания типа ЧОРТ (в украинском, в русском тоже пытались после войны ввести подобное - но не прижилось), и ЧЫЗБУРГЕР (белорусский). В этих языках морфологический принцип менее значим, хотя и сохраняет ведущую роль среди прочих. А вот фонетический играет несколько б**о**льшую роль.

Answer (score 0):

Кстати, хороший вопрос )
Но если с ча-ща и с жи-ши есть устойчивое правило, т.е. их нельзя написать через «ы» ил через «я», то с Вашими примерами только запоминать. Есть много исключений: трущоба (например).
В русском языке слоги ЧО и ЧЁ, ШО и ШЁ, ЖО и ЖЁ, ЩО и ЩЁ читаются одинаково. Сравните: чокнутый — учёба, шов — шёлк, крыжовник — жёлтый, трещотка — щёки.

Comment: Трущоба — это исключение? В этой теме так  много правил и исключений, что иногда одно от другого  не отличишь. Только самый отважный "путник" может  отправиться в Страну шипящих. А если ли там Правило, которое всех главнее и которому подчиняются все остальные?

Comment: К сожалению нет. Здесь словарные слова. Опять же - интуция в помощь!)

Comment: Все слова которые я привел, пишущиеся через о - исключения. Сейчас в школах их зпоминают по классам. Только странновато - начиная с 6-го класса почему-то

Comment: А можно вопрос? Шипящие бывают как мягкие, так и твердые, а правила для них общие. Почему так? Неужели, кроме "шипения",  их ничего не объединяет?

Comment: Ничего, к сожалению

Comment: А вы подумайте!  Иначе  у нас были бы отдельные правила для мягких и твердых шипящих.  Это первый шаг к пониманию темы, и он связан с историей этих звуков. Все они были когда-то мягкими и помнят об этом до сих пор. Нам приходится это учитывать.

Comment: _«В русском языке слоги ЧО и ЧЁ, ШО и ШЁ, ЖО и ЖЁ, ЩО и ЩЁ читаются одинаково»_ — в том то и дело, поэтому нет смысла писать йотированный гласные.

Comment: @Sharon _«Шипящие бывают как мягкие, так и твердые, а правила для них общие»_ — какие именно правила вы имеете в виду?

Comment: @Sharon _«Все они были когда-то мягкими и помнят об этом до сих пор. Нам приходится это учитывать»_ — это может быть справедливо по отношению к _**жи-ши**_, в которых _**ж**_ и _**ш**_ были раньше мягкими, и теперь существует правило, непонятно зачем, сохранять написание с _**и**_, передающее архаичное произношение. Буквы _**ч**_ и _**щ**_ как были мягкими, так и остались.